# How to split wordpress posts table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, posts

I am migrating my news web site to wordpress, and I have performans issues on **wp_posts** table, because of the size of posts. Now **wp_posts** table has around **1,000,000** posts (**4GB**) and the sql query results are terrible. I made partitions on the table but it does not help. I have tried moving most of the posts to another table and create a view named **wp_posts** but the results gone worst.

Can I split wp_posts table or something like that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can read about that in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60944/how-to-split-the-a-table-in-database and here http://www.mindblaze.net/partitioning-tables-improve-wordpress-performance/ and https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/mysql-partitioning-a-quick-look-at-partitioning-separate-your-data-for-faster-searches/